# geolocated gives wrong location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

Im using[GeoLocated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geolocated) package

it shows me wrong `lat` and `lng`
i mean it shows the location in a different country

**could it be something wrong with my country?(forbidding or something)**

here is how i defined options

```
export default geolocated({
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
}) (AddUserPage);
```

and here is the whole code

```
import UserMap from '../map/UserMap';
import { geolocated } from 'react-geolocated';


const AddUserPage = ({coords}) => {
  if (coords) {
   return (
    <div style={{ width: '300px', height: "300pc" }}>
  <UserMap lat={coords.latitude} lng={coords.longitude}></UserMap>
    </div>
  ); 
  }
  return <div></div>
};

export default geolocated({
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
}) (AddUserPage);
```

Comment: Does the device you're using use GPS? If not it could be using the device's IP address which can be inaccurate.

Comment: yes i thing it uses GPS, can it be because of my devise?, because it shows same result at the google maps

Comment: If it also shows the inaccuracy on other apps, then yes it’s likely to be your device.

Comment: thanks for the guidance